I'm converting Markdown files to an ePUB book through Pandoc. How do I insert a page break in the title page when using a custom ePUB template?
I'm creating an ePUB book with Markdown files as inputs through Pandoc. I'm currently trying to make a custom template so that I can include the dedication in the title page before the table of contents. I'm using the following code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops"$if(lang)$ xml:lang="$lang$"$endif$>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
  <title>$pagetitle$</title>
$if(highlighting-css)$
  <style>
$highlighting-css$
  </style>
$endif$
$for(css)$
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$css$" />
$endfor$
$for(header-includes)$
  $header-includes$
$endfor$
</head>
<body$if(coverpage)$ id="cover"$endif$$if(body-type)$ epub:type="$body-type$"$endif$>
$if(titlepage)$
<section epub:type="titlepage" class="titlepage">
$for(title)$
$if(title.type)$
  <h1 class="$title.type$">$title.text$</h1>
$else$
  <h1 class="title">$title$</h1>
$endif$
$endfor$
$if(subtitle)$
  <p class="subtitle">$subtitle$</p>
$endif$
$for(author)$
  <p class="author">$author$</p>
$endfor$
$for(creator)$
  <p class="$creator.role$">$creator.text$</p>
$endfor$
$if(publisher)$
  <p class="publisher">$publisher$</p>
$endif$
$if(date)$
  <p class="date">$date$</p>
$endif$
$if(rights)$
  <div class="rights">$rights$</div>
$endif$
$if(translator)$
  <p class="translator">Translated by $translator$</p>
$endif$
$if(dedication)$
<span style="page-break-after: always" />
<p class="dedication">$dedication$</p>
$endif$
</section>
$else$
$if(coverpage)$
<div id="cover-image">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 $cover-image-width$ $cover-image-height$" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<image width="$cover-image-width$" height="$cover-image-height$" xlink:href="../media/$cover-image$" />
</svg>
</div>
$else$
$for(include-before)$
$include-before$
$endfor$
$body$
$for(include-after)$
$include-after$
$endfor$
$endif$
$endif$
</body>
</html>

With regard to this text in specific,
$if(dedication)$
<span style="page-break-after: always" />
<p class="dedication">$dedication$</p>
$endif$

I was expecting a page break to happen, and yet the output on ePubViewer is such:
Pandoc output.
when I expected the "Dedication" text to appear on the next page.
Is there a way for me to adjust the template so that I achieve this result?

The break-after property, which is probably what should be used here, is ignored if no box is created, so it cannot work on an empty span. Try to add use the break-before property on the <p> element instead.
Readers don't always support the page-break-after property, or do so only when it is set on a heading element like <h3>. See, for example, this issue for epub.js.
